# how to select rows according to another column

Tags: excel

I have a sheet like below:

```
columnA    columnB    columnC    columnD    columnE
10001      aaa        bbb                   10004
10002      mmm        nnn                   10006
10003      yyy        zzz                   10009
10004      uuu        xxx                   10010
10005      fff        ggg
10007      kkk        hhh
10009      rrr        ppp
```

columnA, columnB and columnC have around 60k rows, and columnE has around 800 rows which have the same value scope of columnA.

I want to figure out the rows for the first 3 columns which columnA has a value exists in columnE.

According to [this post](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php), I have tried to use the formula in columnD
`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,$E$2:$E$800,1,FALSE)),"No","Yes")` but Excel always popup a window saying:
`The formula you typed contains an error`

I am not familiar with using function in Excel, can anyone help to give a clue where the error is? I am using Excel 2007

Comment: It works for me, are you sure you're not leaving anything out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me:

[image: my results]

However I have a few things you can try to debug:

1. If you have downladed or exported this data then be sure the file format is not **.xls** and the file hasn't opened in **[compatability]** mode as this will restrict the number of rows allowed. I doubt this is the issue.
2. Try and create you formula in stages to see which of the steps fail, e.g.:

   - `=VLOOKUP(A2,$E$2:$E$800,1,FALSE)` should give the the number e.g. **10004** or **#N/A**
   - `=ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,$E$2:$E$800,1,FALSE))` should give you **TRUE** or **FALSE**
   - `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,$E$2:$E$800,1,FALSE)),"No","Yes")` should give you **Yes** or **No**

Comment: thanks, the debug tips help a lot, I found the root cause is I have changed the `List seperator` in `Reginonal and Language Options` to `|` before, so replace the `,` in the formula to `|` will solve this problem. I finally found this by constructing the formula step by step